# Detect in android widget a touch event from down to up (or the inverse)

Tags: android, android-widget

How I can detect a touch event from down to up (or the inverse) in Android widget (sdk 2.3.3)?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting an OnTouchListener to the widget and getting the event codes with event.getAction();

Suppose your widget is an ImageView. In xml define:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

and in Java, your code would be:

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.DOWN){
             //do something
         }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.UP){
             // do something
         }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.MOVE){
            //do something
         }
     }
}):
```

Comment: Have you an idea how to implement it?

Comment: This code looks like code for normal activity, not widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only setOnClickListeners

I recommend you to read this great answer. [Detect OnTouch on AppWidget. If is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12655881/5980046)