# Detect OnTouch on AppWidget. If is it possible?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, touch-event, ontouchlistener

Detect OnTouch on AppWidget. If is it possible?
Hello! I'm trying to create my first AppWidget for Android 2.1 in which a client may have a chance to select an item on my custom view. I'm going to create a custom view and a slider for it and client may select by pulling slider over the custom view. For this purpose I want to detect onTouch for AppWidget (to determine X-, Y- coordinates), is there way to do this?

I saw a list of valid widgets which can be used in AppWidget:

- AnalogClock
- Button
- Chronometer
- ImageButton
- ImageView
- ProgressBar
- TextView
- ViewFlipper
- ListView
- GridView
- StackView
- AdapterViewFlipper

However they do not fit my needs. I have Googled this but find nothing which could help me.
IS there any way to detect OnTouch within an AppWidget? Perhaps this would require me to have a newer API version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to detect touch on `AppWidget`.RemoteViews have no method to detect it(we can not register a touch listener for them).

Mark Murphy([CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)) in [detect onTouch for widget](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/l55D63fp7PE) says:

> You don't detect "on touch" for app widgets. You can, however, detect
>   clicks, via setOnClickPendingIntent() on RemoteViews. AFAIK, this
>   works for all View classes supported by RemoteViews.

Also,you can not use `StackView` in AppWidgets in Android2.1 (see [simulate stack view in Android2(API 5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286506/simulate-stack-view-in-android2api-5)).