# Android;Force AppWidget to work from SD Card?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-appwidget

Is there any way to force AppWidget to work even App is moved to the SD Card and SD Card is  not `unmounted`? [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot) say:

> ... you should not allow your application to be installed on the external storage if it uses any of the following features, due to the cited consequences ***when the external storage is unmounted***:
>   ...
>   App Widgets
>   Your App Widget will be removed from the home
>   screen. When external storage is remounted, your App Widget will not
>   be available for the user to select until the system resets the home
>   application (usually not until a system reboot).

It seems that docs say AppWidget will be removed from home screen `if` user unmounts SD Card.But When I move the App in emulator to the SD Card (and I do not unmount SD Card) see `problem loading widget` message in Home Screen,also the widget is not available for user in list of widgets.Why?

Comment: Mainly because there is no current way to run a widget (that runs a background process) in the sdcard because the SD-Card is always "asked" to work. What I mean is you can't run a service from an app that is installed on SD-Card. If you look deeply you'll see that almost every  app that has a background process can ONLY be installed in the internal storage. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user2606414 I developed some Apps before that they have services and their services work where App move to SD Card.

Comment: You sure they worked in background?

Comment: @user2606414 Yes,of course.I'm sure.

Comment: Raùl just explained what I meant...  I'm almost sure you can't run a widget from SD-Card...

Answer (score 5):

For now, there is no way to make a Widget to work while the app is installed on the SD-Card. This is the normal behavior even when SD-Card is mounted.

You get the error `problem loading widget` because Widgets are automatically disabled (and removed from the Widget list, so you can't add them) when you move the app to external storage, but they are kept in Home Screen, to be ready when you move it back to the phone and home application is resetted.

If you're going to support that the user move your app to external storage, maybe you can publish another app to only hold your widgets, and configure it so that it can only by installed in the phone. This solves the problem but the user has to download two apps instead of one.

Comment: @Raúl Juárez Thank you for your reply.A part of my question is in about why widget behavior is against what is discussed in docs.Do you have any idea?

Comment: @hasanghaforian I don't know why behavior is different from what is stated in the docs, or why the docs don't mention with clarity why widgets are disabled even if the card is mounted, I believe they avoid show widgets from apps in SD card trying to prevent problems (app breaks, Android losing stability,performance) if the card is removed inadvertently.

Comment: @RaúlJuárez Thank you.It seems that's the only way that works,so I award bounty.But it did not explain difference between Docs and what happen in App.